# unable to draw the circuit in tikz

Tags: circuitikz

I am trying to draw this circuit in tikz, but so far I was able to plac only one inverter. When I placed the second inverter, I have an overlap and I can't manage to find the coordinates of first inverter.

I used the following code:

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/height/.initial=0.8}
\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/width/.initial=0.9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (2,0) node[american not port] (mynot) {} ;
\draw (mynot.in) node[anchor=east] {$x$};
\draw (mynot.out) node[anchor=west]{} coordinate (nIN1)
\draw (nIN1) node[american not port] (mynot2) {} ;
\draw (mynot2.in) node[anchor=east] {};
\draw (mynot2.out) node[anchor=west]{} coordinate (nIN2) ;

\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

EDIT: the picture has the write size now

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/height/.initial=0.8}
\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/width/.initial=0.9}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[node distance = 0pt]
\draw   (0,0)   node[msport, xscale=-1] {}
                    to [short,-] ++ (1,0)
                node[american not port,right]   (not-1) {} 
                node[american not port,
                     right=of not-1]            (not-2) {}
        (not-1.out) -- (not-2.in)
        (not-2.out) to [R,-*]      ++ (2,0)    coordinate (aux1)
                node[american not port,
                     right=of aux1]             (not-3) {}
                node[american and port, 
                     right=of not-3,
                     anchor=in 2]               (and)   {}
        (not-2.out)  to [short,*-]  ++ (0,1) -| (and.in 1)
        node[nmos, rotate=-90, 
             below=9mm of not-3.in,
             anchor=G] (nmos) {} 
        (not-3.in) -- (nmos.G) 
        ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

If you like to ad labels to `circuitikz` nodes, than use of `labels` can help you. For example for the first inverter:

```
node[american not port,right,
     label={[yshift=-4ex]below:Inv 1}]   (not-1) {}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: and is it possible to get more space between the inverters? I would need to add some labels over the wires

Comment: @tairebit, of course it is possible. Just increase `node distance` to desired value. For example to 5mm. But then you need to draw lines between nodes.